# Common Cathode Laser Diode - Photovoltaic photodiode

Tags: power-supply, photodiode, laser-diode

I have a pretty quick question. I am working with a laser diode with an integrated photodiode. The pin configuration has a common cathode connection for bother the laser and photodiode. I want to power the laser diode but also operate the photodiode in photovoltaic mode as you get better response, however I am unsure if this is possible.

My example circuit is shown below, if I apply a voltage across the laser diode and then for sake of argument connect a resistor unto ground across the photodiode for a probe to measure the voltage induced from the photodiode current. Will the Current source, which is a lab supply with current limit, not provide an additional unaccounted for voltage across both the photodiode and resistor?

Is there a circuit setup that will allow me to operate the photodiode in photovoltaic mode without voltage/current being supplied to the laser diode affecting it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsLUyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The current source and model numbers of the LED and photodiode are purely as symbol representations, they are not the relevant numbers or codes respectively of my setup.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a circuit setup that will allow me to operate the photodiode
>   in photovoltaic mode without voltage/current being supplied to the
>   laser diode affecting it?'

You bet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQSDcX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But, of course, you'll probably have noticed that this isn't much different from your original circuit.

Comment: So is this Falstad circuit simulation show that the voltage applied to the laserdiode will not affect the photdiode?
[link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+3+0.000005+10.200277308269968+50+5+43%0Av+184+176+184+224+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ad+280+224+280+176+1+0.805904783%0Ai+360+176+360+224+0+0.1%0Aw+280+176+312+176+0%0Aw+312+176+360+176+0%0Aw+312+176+312+144+0%0Aw+312+144+184+144+0%0Aw+184+144+184+176+0%0Aw+184+224+184+272+0%0Aw+184+272+280+272+0%0Aw+280+272+280+224+0%0Ar+360+224+360+272+0+100%0Aw+360+272+440+272+0%0Aw+440+272+440+144+0%0Aw+440+144+312+144+0%0A)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I1 loops through the diode, and that's all. How could it go through D2?